# Firebase users set?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on application for diabetes users. I have manage to create register user button and it works but I want also a new admin to be added to system. The problem is that in admins login page, the normal user can also login. How can I implement this ... I need help please?

```js
document.getElementById("btnSignUp").addEventListener('click', e=>{
  const userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  const userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
   console.log(error.message);
  });
})

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
 //window.location = 'main.html'

    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";


    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(user != null){

      var email_id = user.email;
  document.getElementById("user_para").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + email_id;
      

    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.

    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";

  }
});


function login(){

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });

}

function logout(){
  firebase.auth().signOut();
  window.location='index.html'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to declare specific users with a specific role, "admin" for example:

You set a security rule like the one below for the data you want to be readable only by an "admin":

```
".read": "auth != null && root.child('admins/' + auth.uid).exists()"
```

And you declare the uids of the "admin" users as children of an "admins" database node:

```
- admins
  -h7yic7LeS123asdfsdgwPrfKZ2: true.     //<- key = uid of a admin user
```

Your non-admin users may still be able to see your web page but they will not be able to get the data you normally display in this page for an admin.